# Linux getenv() could not get $PS1 or $PS2

Tags: c, linux, shell, environment-variables

My home world is to write a shell. and I must use `$PS2`.

but when I write a code like this:

```
char *ENV_ps2;
ENV_ps2 = getenv("PS2");
```

I just found `ENV_ps2` was point to `(null)`.

how could I get the `$PS2` in my program ?

Comment: I presume you've confirmed that this shell variable exists, has been EXPORTed, etc...?

Comment: This is the way to go. Is the `PS2` environment variable actually defined?

Comment: yes, I run `echo $PS2`, it print `>`

Comment: @thlgood that doesn't mean it's exported as an environment variable, only that it's available as a local shell variable.

Comment: To check for environment variables, as opposed to plain (non-environment) variables, you can use either (builtin) `export` with no arguments or (not builtin) `env` with no arguments.  Using `export` tells you what the shell thinks it exports; using `env` tells you what was actually in the environment of `env` (what the shell actually exported).  The two usually agree.

Answer (score 9):

The `PS1` and `PS2` shell variables are not *exported* and are therefore inaccessible from child processes.  You can test this with a simple script:

```
$ cat /tmp/pstest.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo PS1=$PS1
echo PS2=$PS2


$ /tmp/pstest.sh 
PS1=
PS2=
```

Comment: ...so technically they're not *environment* variables.  They're local shell variables.

Comment: @larsks: Right. And your comment would be equally correct, and clearer, without the word "technically".

Answer (score 2):

In bash, `$PS1` and `$PS2` are shell variables, not environment variables (at least normally). They're set to default values within bash itself, or set explicitly by the user either interactively or in a startup script such as `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

They can't be accessed via `getenv()`, and they aren't inherited by forked subprocesses. They're managed internally by the shell's own mechanism for shell variables.

If you're writing your own shell, it probably makes sense to do something similar.

You might take a look at the bash source code. It's large and complex, but searching for `PS1` and `PS2` might be instructive. (You don't have to use exactly the same mechanism bash uses; it's likely you'll want something simpler.)

(You can type `export PS1` to turn `$PS1` into an environment variable, but it doesn't make much sense to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

Those env vars are not exported.

If you want a non-portable approach, you could just define and export an arbitrary environment variable, and set PS1/PS2 to that value in your .bashrc/.bash_profile.

eg:

```
# bashrc
MY_PS1="..........."
export $MY_PS1

...
...
...
PS1=$MY_PS1
```